# Improvement Request Add Comment functionality (partially?) broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

So I got two notifications in my inbox this morning.  One that linked to an [article itself](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/minecraft/9740/writing-minecraft-mods#t=201706251502272626792) and one that linked to the [discussion page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/minecraft/9740/writing-minecraft-mods/discussion?page=1&pagesize=30&tab=active&type=all#itemid=14647&itemtype=improvementrequests).  Both improvement request notes are the same note on the same topic/example with the same timestamp.

However here's the kicker:

[image: Comment button doesn't work]

The "add comment" link on the article doesn't work.

I clicked it several times before changing tabs over to the discussion page and using *that* add-comment button (which worked fine).  Upon reloading both tabs prior to making this bug report, my added comment appears in both places and both "add comment" links now work (I suspect that the code somehow sees no comments as being a different case than one+ comments).

Comment: Hmmm, I cannot reproduce this.  Can you see if clicking "add a comment" on [this active improvement request](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/3421/11806) does anything?  Thank you!

Comment: @JarrodDixon Thanks for taking a look, but no, that one works fine. Must've been a weird once-off (possible the page failed to load a JS file).  The duplicate notifications in my inbox might be worth looking at, though.

Comment: Sure, we can check the duplicates out - thanks again for reporting.

Answer (score 1):

The duplicates here were an interesting case.  Basically, you got notified by two different notification systems (watching a tag, and participating in discussion) that weren't aware of each other.

The tag watching system, which runs on a schedule, now consults discussion to make sure you haven't already been notified of an item via that route.

This fix was deployed in the latest build.

Comment: Neat! Thanks for the fix. I did run into the other problem again, but I was able to verify that it was because the page had not fully loaded (I was on a standard Q&A page that time).